# Time reversal in second quantization

Tags: mathematical-physics, second-quantization, time-reversal-symmetry

Let $\mathscr{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the Hilbert space of single-particle states and let $\mathscr{F}$ denote the corresponding Fock space (let's say fermion). Then the time-reversal operator $T$ on $\mathscr{H}$ is just complex conjugation. It would then be reasonable to say that the induced time-reversal operator $T$ on $\mathscr{F}$ is an anti-unitary map on $\mathscr{F}$ such that $T c^*(f) T^*=c^*(Tf)$ where $c^*$ are the creation operators. However, are there any references that such an induced anti-unitary operator exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this is actually pretty easy to define. We can define $W_T: \mathscr{F}\to \mathscr{F}$ by
$$
W_T = J\oplus T\oplus T^{\otimes 2} \oplus \cdots
$$
where $J$ is complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$. It's then easy to check that $W_T$ is anti-unitary and $W_T c^*(f) W_T^* = c^*(Tf)$.